# Visible=false - no errors, but jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a really tough time trying to get jQuery to work; probably because I never really learned Javascript.

My method **hide_all** does not work, so I don't even know if the rest of it does anything yet.

What is wrong with this? It is for a personal webpage (some of us still do that).

```js
$().ready(function() {
  hide_all();
});

function hide_all() {
  $('div[class=private_stock]').visible = false;
};
$('#hrefBox1').click(function() {
  hide_all();
  $('#hrefBox1').show('slow');
});
$('#hrefBox2').click(function() {
  hide_all();
  $('#hrefBox2').show('slow');
});
$('#hrefBox3').click(function() {
  hide_all();
  $('#hrefBox3').show('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a id="hrefBox1" href="#">Box 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="hrefBox2" href="#">Box 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="hrefBox3" href="#">Box 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="divBulls" class="private_stock">
  <div style="background-color:blue;height:400px;width:800px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="divCows" class="private_stock">
  <div style="background-color:red;height:400px;width:800px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="divCalves" class="private_stock">
  <div style="background-color:green;height:400px;width:800px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the main issue in your code is :
-- when calling show you have provided the id of the 'hrefs' which is acting on the links. whereas when the 'hide_all' function is trying to set the 'private_stock' to hide..

Strange that you are not using 'hide()' function of jquery to 'hide all'...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a id="hrefBox1" href="#">Box 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="hrefBox2" href="#">Box 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="hrefBox3" href="#">Box 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="divBulls" class="private_stock">
  <div style="background-color:blue;height:400px;width:800px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="divCows" class="private_stock">
  <div style="background-color:red;height:400px;width:800px;"></div>
</div>
<div id="divCalves" class="private_stock">
  <div style="background-color:green;height:400px;width:800px;"></div>
</div>

<script>
$().ready(function() {
  hide_all();
});

function hide_all() {
  $('div[class=private_stock]').hide();
};
$('#hrefBox1').click(function() {
  hide_all();
  $('#divBulls').show('slow');
});
$('#hrefBox2').click(function() {
  hide_all();
  $('#divCows').show('slow');
});
$('#hrefBox3').click(function() {
  hide_all();
  $('#divCalves').show('slow');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think I write better code in the morning. I can't believe I missed putting the href references where the div references go. That got it, 100%. Thanks Jas!

Comment: Maybe somebody can give me an upvote, though.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to hide visible divs  use `:visible` selector and `.hide()` to hide it

```
$('div[class=private_stock]:visible').hide();
```

or you can use

```
$('div.private_stock').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such property like `.visible` in jQuery. Use `.hide()`.
Moreover, there is no need to make `[class='private-stock']` selector - you need to use `.private-stock`.

```
 $('div.private-stock').hide();
```

Actually, jQuery never uses properties for objects. You will never see something like:

```
var x = $("div").style;
$("div").class = "myClass";
```

It always uses methods.

Comment: Always uses methods? That I can remember. I thought .hide() was to control how fast it was to hide because it took a parameter. Thanks!